# How to tell if an application is in modal state

Tags: macos, modal-dialog, macos-carbon

I want to be able to tell if my application is currently in a "modal" state.

I know that if it is in this state using Cocoa's functions, I could tell by checking where `[[NSApplication sharedApplication] modalWindow]` returns nil or not.

But it could also be in modal state using Carbon's functions (`RunAppModalLoopForWindow` etc), and then Cocoa's `modalWindow` does not tell us whether the application is modal.

Unfortunately, I don't have the choice to avoid Carbon as my app hosts old third party plugins which do use it.

Here's part of an example stack trace in a modal state due to carbon:

```
frame #12: 0x93ede739 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1897
frame #13: 0x93eddd5a CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 394
frame #14: 0x93eddbbb CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
frame #15: 0x930cee2d HIToolbox`RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 259
frame #16: 0x930cebb2 HIToolbox`ReceiveNextEventCommon + 526
frame #17: 0x93119c4a HIToolbox`AcquireNextEventInMode + 75
frame #18: 0x93269aea HIToolbox`_AcquireNextEvent + 58
frame #19: 0x932585dc HIToolbox`_RunAppModalLoop + 168
frame #20: 0x932584ee HIToolbox`RunAppModalLoopForWindow + 130
```

I could trace the stack and see that `_RunAppModalLoop` is there, but I don't like this solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by enumerating all the app's windows and checking if they are modal by using `GetWindowModality`.

```
bool isAnyCarbonWindowModal()
{
    for (
        WindowRef win = GetFrontWindowOfClass(kAllWindowClasses, true);
        win != nullptr;
        win = GetNextWindowOfClass(win, kAllWindowClasses, true))
    {
        WindowModality modalKind;
        WindowRef unavailableWindow;
        GetWindowModality(win, &modalKind, &unavailableWindow);
        if (kWindowModalityAppModal == modalKind)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You don't need a nested loop to enumerate all the Carbon windows.  One way is to get the first one by `w = GetFrontWindowOfClass( kAllWindowClasses, true )` and then get each next one with `w = GetNextWindowOfClass( w, kAllWindowClasses, true )`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try checking the output from `GetWindowModality([[NSApp keyWindow] windowRef], ...)` and/or the same applied to the `-mainWindow`.

Comment: `[NSApp keyWindow]` returns `nil`. However I found a different solution using this `GetWindowModality`, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can see if `-[NSRunLoop currentMode]` is `NSDefaultRunLoopMode`.

However, you might get a different answer with a question more specific to the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: it results in `NSDefaultRunLoopMode` when running modal via Carbon. and same with `CFRunLoopCopyCurrentMode(CFRunLoopGetCurrent())`.